# Write array into range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with 2 named columns: "GCGAR6" and "GCBARB". I have an array named "codes". "nbrLines" is a variable defined in my code.
In the column "GCGAR6", a value is repeated 63 times, then comes another value, etc... I would like to paste my array "codes" into the column "GCBARB" each time I encounter a new value in "GCGAR6". The problem is that my code outputs the array only once.

```
For Each n In .Range("GCGAR6").Resize(nbrLines + 1, 1)
    If n.Value <> n.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
    .Range("GCBARB").Resize(UBound(codes) + 1) = Application.Transpose(codes)
    End If
Next niveau
```

Comment: 1. What is your problem? There is no error description. • 2. please show how the array `codes` is generated and filled with data. Note that you need a 2 dimensional array to write it into a range even if it is only one column. • 3. What is `niveau.`? This should throw an error. • Please see [mcve] and provide a full example that is reproduceable.

Comment: this `.Range("GCBARB").Resize(UBound(codes) + 1)` doesn't really on the for each statement as far as I can see.  so it may be outputing the array hundreds of times but in the same place